# How can I seperate the JSON response data from Openweathermap with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, openweathermap

I am trying to get the temperature and humidity value from OpenWeatherMap from PHP to my web page. Even though I am able to communicate with the api link and get a complete data. I cannot separate and get the temperature and humidity data individually.

[image: The picture of the website]

What I am trying to do is instead of showing the JSON response as a block, just getting the temperature and humidity data to the below of the website.

https://openweathermap.org/current -> here is the link contains JSON response, you can check the response under the title "Weather parameters in API response".

Here is the code:

```
<div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
<?php
$url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Istanbul&mode=html&units=metric&APPID=...";     

$getweather = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($getweather);

$gettemperature = $data['main']['temp'];
$gethumidity =  $data['main']['humidity'];

echo $getweather;

?>

        <h3>Weather in Istanbul</h3>
        <span>Temperature: </span> <?php echo $gettemperature; ?><br>
        <span>Humidity: </span> <?php echo $gethumidity; ?><br>
</div>
<script>
```

Unfortunately I am very new with the PHP topics. I think I am having a fault with the PHP syntax or doing this all wrong trying to do it with PHP, so I would really appreciate the support. Thank you so much.

Comment: `json_decode()` returns objects rather than associative arrays unless you use the second argument `true`.

Comment: So it should be `$data->main->temp`.

Comment: I've been using OWM recently as well, but with Java. What I'm doing is that I map the JSON to a Java model object that basically structurally represents the JSON. I am not really an expert on PHP5+, but I'm sure there is something that allows you to map it to an object as well. It's much easier to just ask for `WeatherResponse->getHumidity()`.. It feels more robust than just trying to hack it our of the received JSON. Just an idea.

Comment: Is it possible that I am calling the JSON wrong? I tried "$data->main->temp" and "json_decode($getweather,true);" but it is still not working. Maybe because of the structure of the API I'm not getting a response?

Comment: Also I found that the problem is with decoding. Before the decoding I have a string(2236), but after decoding it is a NULL, even though I set the json_decode as true.

Comment: Solved the problem!! Yes, it was "$data->main->temp" but the url link was wrong. It was trying to decode the html link not a JSON. So after changing the link and correcting the data calls, it worked. Thank you very much.